# Como puede elevar x al cuadrado o a cualquier potencia sin que me de error?

Tags: c#

El problema es que necesito resolver una ecuación de segundo grado ax**2+bx+c pero no se como elevar la x a una potencia porque es un string y no un número y me da error

Comment: covierte el string en un double con double.Parse

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Si lo que quieres es resolver una ecuación de segundo grado, no necesitas elevar la x al cuadrado, sino utilizar los coeficientes para resolverla.
La ecuación de segundo grado tiene esta solución:
[image: Solución de una ecuación de segundo grado]

Se supone que la ecuación de segundo grado que te pasan está bien formada. Por ejemplo, la siguiente ecuación:

```
$ec = "-2x**2-5x+4";
```

tiene 3 coeficientes reales. Para calcular el coeficiente a, debemos obtener los caracteres hasta el x**2 y convertirlo en entero

```
$a = (int) substr($ec, 0, strpos($ec, 'x**2'));
```

Como ves, empezamos por la posición cero de la cadena, pues debemos obtener también el signo.
Para obtener el siguiente coeficiente debemos empezar a buscar en la posición después de x**2 y seguir hasta la siguiente x

```
$offsetA = strpos($ec, 'x**2') + 4;
$offsetB = strpos($ec, 'x', $offsetA);
$b = (int) substr($ec, $offsetA, $offsetB - $offsetA);
```

O sea, primero obtenemos la posición después de x**2, y luego la posición donde está la siguiente x. Con esos datos ya podemos obtener la posición del segundo coeficiente.
Ahora vamos con el tercero. Éste no tiene una x a la que multiplicar (en realidad sí que la tiene, pero es x**0, que es igual a 1 sea cual sea el valor de x). Como ya conocemos la posición de la segunda x, que calculamos en $offsetB, no hay más que sumarle 1 a esa posición y dejar que busque hasta el final de la ecuación:

```
$c = (int) substr($ec, $offsetB + 1);
```

Ahora ya, conociendo los coeficientes, no tenemos más que aplicar la fórmula para calcular el valor de x, y esta solución dependerá del valor del discriminante, si es mayor que 0, tendrá dos soluciones distintas, si es igual a 0, tendrá dos soluciones iguales, y si es menor que 0 no tendrá soluciones reales y tendremos que irnos al mundo imaginario, donde encontraremos dos soluciones imaginarias

Comment: La pregunta es **cómo elevar un número al cuadrado**. No es **cómo resolver una ecuación de segundo grado**.

Comment: @Mateo, bueno, la pregunta empieza por "El problema es que necesito resolver una ecuación de segundo grado"

Comment: Solo quería dar una explicación al voto negativo que recibiste. Es posible que sea por eso. Además se le pidió que aclare el problema y todavía no lo hizo. Por eso es mejor esperar a que la pregunta mejore antes de responder.